# How does the White Walkers' undead-spell spread?

Tags: game-of-thrones

We've been shown in *Game of Thrones* that people who die north of The Wall *can* end up becoming wights (another footman in the army of the dead), and we also know that anyone killed by a White Walker (or in the vicinity of one, by a wight) is also a candidate for joining the army of the dead.

We also know, now (spoilers for S07E06)...

> ... that the control over a group of wights is localised to individual White Walkers - meaning that killing a White Walker who is magically linked to a group of wights will "de-activate" those wights, leaving them permanently dead (until another White Walker might walk in and revive them with magic again).

**Q: Do we know all the possible ways this spell of animating the dead, which has been compared to zombieism, can propagate?** Is it possible, for example, for a lone wight in a populated area to make other people wights

(i.e. if a wight kills someone, does that someone become a wight, too, like a zombie? Or do they have to be near a White Walker?)

Comment: @LeonX `White Walker (Wight)` It would appear that you are confused. White Walkers **are not** the same as wights. My question here is regarding the **wights** and not the White Walkers.

Answer (score 3):

I figure only the White Walkers raise the Wights. In the battle in the ending of season 5 episode 8, the Wights kills tons of people who stay dead until the Night King  [shows off to Jon as he is fleeing, by raising every dead person from the fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wn6HPuTJrgA).

Comment: The Night's Watch burn bodies (S07E06 - Jon says Thoros must be burned) specifically to prevent them from turning into wights **automatically**. It's not impossible that the Night's King is actively resurrecting all the dead (effectively broadcasting a resurrection spell, and resurrecting all the dead), but this does seem different from how the Night's King raised the dead at Hardhome. I think a full explanation hinges on how the Walkers are affecting winter in the first place (it has been hinted by GRRM that the irregular seasons will be resolved in the end)

Answer (score 2):

They seem some sort of [**necromancers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necromancy) to me. They can raise the dead and control them. And from what we saw in [Hardhome](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3866850/),

It's as easy for a white walker to raise the dead as lifting his hands

[image]

Although the term "necromancers" won't completely fit since they don't seem to use magic (Spells/spoken words). **The magic involved** (if there's any) seems to **come from the White Walkers themselves**.

Here's a quote from the books

> Melisandre: **Necromancy animates these wights**, yet they are still only dead flesh. Steel and fire will serve for them. The ones you call the Others are something more.

And

> Is it possible, for example, for a lone wight in a populated area to make other people wights?

No, Because it's not an infection to be spread, it's a magical power (most likely) that don't allow the White Walkers to resurrect them, but rather control them like if they're puppets.

> Wights in the novels are indeed not exactly like zombies: **they can't turn other people into wights with infectious bites**, every body part keeps moving even if amputated, etc. (the term "revenant" is a closer description). [Source](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Wights#Behind_the_scenes)

Here's an example (from min 3:10) for people get bitten by Whites and don't turn until The White Walkers raise them:

[image]

[image]

A man with a bite mark will start to twitch while the Walker is raising his hand

[image]

[image]

Comment: What this answer doesn't address is whether a wight can turn other people into wights after killing them (kinda like conventional zombies). What we can infer so far is that whenever a wight kills someone, a White Walker has always been close-by enough to quickly animate them, too, but it's just an assumption: it may be that within a wight exists the magic to spread the spell without a White Walker being in the vicinity: **that's what I'm after**.

Comment: Oh! and no, they can't, it's magic not an infection. Not sure if I'll find a specific proof to that, but it seemed obvious to me.

Comment: I know it's magic - notice I wrote "the White Walkers' **spell**", and only compared them to zombies in the ways that they *are* similar. It's not an infection in the literal, contagious disease sense, but it might be that the White Walkers have imbued within the wights the ability to curse dead bodies (who knows? - that's kind of my question).

Comment: That's why I posted that Wikia quote, and That the White Walkers control them like puppets. Also there are examples in "Hardhome" to people get bitten and don't turn, until the White Walker did. Not sure if this is the main point you're asking for.

Comment: I thought about what would happen if a wight made it to King's Landing (as they have planned), is it at all possible that the wight would cause an outbreak (maybe the Walkers can remote control him and through him cause others to turn).

Comment: From what we have seen, no. And there are a lot of dead south of the wall, If the Walkers has "raising the dead" ability from that distance/beyond the wall, they would've done it already.

Comment: I really don't see how they would. It would only make sense if they would be able to choose when to raise dead, which I highly doubt they can. The video I posted show that even though the Wights killed a lot of people, they were only raised when the Night King raised his arms.

Comment: @madmada `they would've done it already` It's possible that the wights work like a radio repeater. The last time we saw a wight beyond the wall was in S01, and he killed many members of the Night's Watch, and they immediately burned all the bodies **out of fear that they would rise again**. It may be that they were just being careful, but what *if* the wight had actually managed to make all those kills would-be wights, somehow?

Comment: We've seen something in S07E06 that lends credence to his idea I bring up about the magic in these wights working like a `radio repeater`, btw. I mentioned it in the question (in spoiler quotes).

Comment: I guess they may be able to (Although, it was mentioned that the wall contains spells and magic stopping the Walkers. Also, Benjin while saving Bran hinted that he can't go south of the wall, so we still to see how the show will address this point). Still, if they're able to, it'll probably be the same way they raise the dead north of the wall, with close proximity to them and regardless of how they died.

Comment: `but rather control them like if they're puppets` The wights seem to be conscious to a degree. Evidenced by Sandor throwing stones, which alerts the wights that they can cross the ice again. The jawless wight clearly puzzles this together himself, and him moving forwards alerts this to the other wights. The wights also responded to Jon coming out of the water (end of S07E06), and no White Walker saw him (as far as we have seen). While the wights can be commanded, it does seem that they have a base consciousness to them.

Comment: It seems that way from the last episode, and it's impractical to have to control every single White. I don't think we'll know for sure (at least not this season). But I agree that base conscience and being commanded, controlled is most likely.